# Concatenation of two varchar columns in select into

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a `insert into tableA select from someTables` and in my `select` I have two text columns that I concatenate e.g. `colA + colB`. They have type `varchar(n)`. Should the column in `TableA` simply be `varchar(2n)`? Is it bad for performance if say I have `varchar(5*n)`?

If the two columns are concatenated from `varchar(n)` is it possible that the result is more than `varchar(2n)` or e.g. `nvarchar(3n)`?

Comment: To your second question, no, that's not possible (barring some weirdness maybe from different encodings).  Yes, your target column should be large enough to hold the concatenated string, unless you don't mind losing information.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen. What about the `nvarchar()` part when inputs are `varchar`? It is also waste I quess...?

Comment: Check the @Larnu answer below.  Too long for a single comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you concatenate 2 `(n)varchar` values the resulting datatype is the 2 length properties added together, or 8,000 bytes (which ever is **lower**). If you concatenating a `varchar` and an `nvarchar` the `varchar` will be implicitly cast to an `nvarchar` first.

Unless at least 1 of the values concatenated is of `MAX` length, the return datatype will not be converted to a `MAX` and any trailing characters will be truncated.

Take the below examples, which return the data types of their aliases:

```sql
SELECT REPLICATE('A',10) + REPLICATE('B',10) AS varchar20,
       REPLICATE(N'A',10) + REPLICATE(N'B',10) AS nvarchar20,
       REPLICATE(N'A',10) + REPLICATE('B',5) AS nvarchar15,
       REPLICATE('A',5000) + REPLICATE('B',5000) AS varchar8000, --Truncation occurs
       REPLICATE(N'A',3000) + REPLICATE('B',3000) AS nvarchar4000, --Truncation occurs
       REPLICATE(CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX),N'A'),3000) + REPLICATE('B',3000) AS nvarcharMAX;
```

And this can be validated using `dm_exec_describe_first_result_set`:

```sql
SELECT [name], system_type_name
FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(N'SELECT REPLICATE(''A'',10) + REPLICATE(''B'',10) AS varchar20,
       REPLICATE(N''A'',10) + REPLICATE(N''B'',10) AS nvarchar20,
       REPLICATE(N''A'',10) + REPLICATE(''B'',5) AS nvarchar15,
       REPLICATE(''A'',5000) + REPLICATE(''B'',5000) AS varchar8000, --Truncation occurs
       REPLICATE(N''A'',3000) + REPLICATE(''B'',3000) AS nvarchar4000, --Truncation occurs
       REPLICATE(CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX),N''A''),3000) + REPLICATE(''B'',3000) AS nvarcharMAX;',NULL, NULL);
```

Obviously, if you concatenate 3 `(n)varchar` values, then the resulting length is the sum of the 3 length values, etc.

Note that I explicitly state 8,000 **bytes** not 8,000 or 4,000 characters length. Many confuse the length value for `varchar` and `nvarchar` to mean the number of characters it can hold, but this is not actually true, it's the number of bytes; for `varchar` it's 8,000 single bytes and for `nvarchar` it is 4,000 double bytes. This is far more important now that SQL Server supports UTF-8 collations.

For example, the below returns a value of `2666`, as the character I chose at random (`◘`) uses **3** bytes per character.

```sql
SELECT LEN(REPLICATE(CONVERT(varchar(3),N'◘' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC_UTF8),8000));
```

Comment: Thanks. Can two `varchar`become `navarchar`? Maybe stupid quesiton but just need to be sure before I change it...

Comment: A `varchar` cannot become an `nvarchar` without conversion, be that explicit or implicit, @David . No value can change its data type unless there is some kind of conversion (that includes going from a non-`MAX` to `MAX` length and vice-versa as well).

Comment: Say I have a fixed Lenght of data, e.g. "David" how can I determine the number of bytes in SQL Server and if it is ASCII or UNICODE? I know ASCII is subset of UNICODE but how to check if ASCII is enough?

Comment: To get the size of a string type in SQL Server, @David , you would use `DATALENGTH`. Though youa re starting to move into a new question here.

Comment: @David See [`SQL_Variant_Property`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sql-variant-property-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). for a way to examine data types, sizes, ... .